# what is the type of this function?

Tags: haskell

I have 2 exercises to complete, the first one should create tuples from 2 lists, it's done. **My doubt is on the second exercise**

```
Input
createlist [1,2] ['a','b','c']

Output
[[(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(1,'c')],[(2,'a'),(2,'b'),(2,'c')]]
```

On the second exercice, they ask me the type of the function `f`:

```
createlist l1 l2 = map (f l2) l1 
               where f l x = ...
```

to my understanding, the f function here only receives a list (**l2**), why is there 2 arguments in the **f** function bellow?

**EDIT**

Thank you all for the insights, i got it to work.

Here it is:

```
linhaz :: [a] -> [b] -> [[(a,b)]]
linhaz [] _ = []
linhaz _ [] = []
linhaz l1 l2 = map (f l2) l1
                where 
                    f [] x = []
                    f l x = (x,head l):(f (tail l) x)
```

Comment: Look at the type and definition of `map` for a hint.

Comment: `f` doesn't really take 2 arguments, `f` takes one argument and returns yet another function.  `f l` is itself a function, which can take an argument (like `x`).  `f` is a "curried function".

Comment: Thank you guys, it was a stupid doubt.

Comment: Note that your solution won't work since `f [] x` is not handled.

Comment: You are right, added all the exhaustive patterns :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function passed to map must only take one argument. However a function with more arguments can be partially applied (or [curried](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#curried-functions)), in which case it returns a new function that only takes the parameters you didn't supply.

So if f is a function that takes 2 arguments (let's call them a and b), then `(f l2)` returns a new function in which a is already set to be 'l2' so the only thing you need to apply is a value for b.

So f is a two-argument function, and we convert it into a one-argument function to pass it to map.

Comment: Thank you for the insights Pat :)